# Is there any way to attach Microsoft.NETCore.App to my WinUI3 program?

Tags: .net, winui-3

I build an APP with WinUI 3 using .Net7.0, and it runs well on my PC. But after I installed it on a laptop, it is failing to launch, and there is a MessageBox says I must install or update .NET to run it (Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0).

[Screenshot] https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEjl0.png)

So I guess maybe I can attack this framework to my APP? Then other users will not have to install it by themselves?

I clicked the button "Yes" on the screenshot, and I can download and install .Net, but I want to do this automatically while installing my APP, is there any way to achive that? Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Your installer should be the one that will install are prerequisites before you install the app. Not sure which installer do you use ?

Comment: It's a packaged WinUI 3 App, and I generated a .MSIX file with Visual Studio, which can be uploaded on Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making your app [self-contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/self-contained-deploy/deploy-self-contained-apps)? Open the app's *.csproj and inside the `PropertyGroup` add this line:

```xml
<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Although it didn't work for me with <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>, I followed this direction and found a solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/3295): Setting <SelfContained> to `true` solved my problem!

Comment: The WindowsAppSDK runtime might be required when you install the app without `<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>`.

Comment: Thank you, just to be safe I will add both marks